# Tool to monitor HTTP, TCP, etc. Web Service traffic

Tags: web-services, http, tcp, monitoring

What's the best tool that you use to monitor Web Service, SOAP, WCF, etc. traffic that's coming and going on the wire? I have seen some tools that made with Java but they seem to be a little crappy. What I want is a tool that sits in the middle as a proxy and does port redirection (which should have configurable listen/redirect ports). Are there any tools work on Windows to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question so good :) - Do you want to monitor traffic or do you want to do some shaping/policing/redirecting/prioritizing of traffic as well?

Comment: I want to monitor the traffic because I don't want to accidentally send very large object graphs over the wire.

Comment: Also new one + HTTPS: http://www.tcpcatcher.org/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For Windows HTTP, you can't beat [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com). You can use it as a [reverse proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp) for port-forwarding on a web server. It doesn't necessarily need IE, either. It can [use other clients](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp).

Comment: by default fiddler does not listen to traffic directed for localhost - to use it in development use your machine name as the endpoint

Comment: Yeah, I use Fiddler a lot during web development but AFAIK it is working in tandem with IE. Is there any way to configure it so that I can use it in between my web service server and client?

Comment: Fiddler is just a debugging proxy, if you configure your client to use to use 127.0.0.1:8888 as a proxy you will see all the traffic going through fiddler.  You can also enable it for remote clients as well.

Comment: for the Microsoft WebDev webserver you cant use the machine name becasue it doesn't listen for it. instead you can use http:// ipv4.fiddler:82913/products/1002 for your site and fiddler will see that

Answer (score 14):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) does not do port redirection, but sniffs and interprets a lot of protocols.

Comment: Wireshark is good but it is a little low-level tool that watches ethernet-level traffic. What I want is a tool for dedicated web service use with an appropriate UI that can show pretty XML tree, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You might find [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f4db40af-1e08-4a21-a26b-ec2f4dc4190d&DisplayLang=en) helpful if you're on Windows.

Comment: This is now called Microsoft Message Analyzer - https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=44226

Answer (score 6):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or Tshark) is probably the defacto standard traffic inspection tool. It is unobtrusive and works without fiddling with port redirecting and proxying. It is very generic, though, as does not (AFAIK) provide any tooling specifically to monitor web service traffic - it's all tcp/ip and http.

You have probably already looked at [tcpmon](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/) but I don't know of any other tool that does the sit-in-between thing.

Comment: Yes, I have looked tcpmon and it's the best I have found so far but can be developed further IMO. Probably I will write my own tool :)

Answer (score 5):

I tried Fiddler with its reverse proxy ability which is mentioned by @marxidad  and it seems to be working fine, since Fiddler is a familiar UI for me and has the ability to show request/responses in various formats (i.e. Raw, XML, Hex), I accept it as an answer to this question. One thing though. I use WCF and I got the following exception with reverse proxy thing:

> The message with To 'http://localhost:8000/path/to/service' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree

I have figured out (thanks Google, erm.. I mean Live Search :p) that this is because my endpoint addresses on server and client differs by port number. If you get the same exception consult to the following MSDN forum message:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2302537&SiteID=1

which recommends to use clientVia Endpoint Behavior explained in following MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for the last couple of years. Very pleased with it.

Answer (score 3):

I second [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). It is very powerful and versatile.
And since this tool will work not only on Windows but also on Linux or Mac OSX, investing your time to learn it (quite easy actually) makes sense. Whatever the platform or the language you use, it makes sense.

Regards,

Richard
Just Programmer
http://sili.co.nz/blog

Comment: The link http://sili.co.nz/blog doesn't work, looks like the domain sili.co.nz doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I find [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) very powerful

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

**JMeter's built-in proxy** may be used to record all HTTP request/response information.

Firefox "**Live HTTP headers**" plugin may be used to see what is happening on the browser side when sending/receiving request.

Firefox "**Tamper data**" plugin may be useful when you need to intercept and modify request.

Answer (score -2):

I use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) to generate graphs and look for elements in IIS logs.