# How to intercept xml response and request during web service invocation?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I wonder if there is some neat way to intercept xml request send during java webservice method invocation and xml given in response? I don't want to print those xmls to standard output but to "catch" them in some string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, normally you use a soap proxy like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Simply point your webservice client at the proxy and the proxy at the real service.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler or SoapUI will let you see and even CHANGE the request/response in route.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a packet sniffer and see what's in your traffic.

I have never got that far.

What I have used is a very simple home made protocol, that reads all the input, print it and re-send all the info.

Answer (score 0):

[Tool to monitor HTTP, TCP, etc. Web Service traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120022/tool-to-monitor-http-tcp-etc-web-service-traffic)
may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can deploy servlets on the server providing the web service you might consider writing and deploying a simple Filter. You can use this to log both the inbound and the outbound traffic.