# XSLT namespaces URL

Tags: xslt

What does a namespace do in XSLT when a url is provided such as:

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

does this attempt to make a connection to the internet?

Comment: No; it just so happens that when the specification was devised, URI's (of which URL's are the most common) were decided upon for the format for the namespace.

Comment: No, unplug your network cable and turn off any wifi -- and run the transformation to see that it is still successfully performed. A namespace must be some unique string. Strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be a URL -- one can use any string as long as it uniquely identifies his XML vocabulary. Try specifying elements in this namespace: "'!@#$%%^123'" -- you'll find that the XML document is well-formed and there is no error raised dealing with this document.

Answer (score 1):

No; it just so happens that the specification for XML Namespaces (see [W3C XSL Namespace specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)) are URI's.

They work in exactly the same way that namespaces in other languages do; they help uniquely identify things with the same names but in different contexts.

You can prove that no attempt is made to retrieve the resource by using a HTTP Monitor on your machine while loading or using the XSL Transformation - this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120022/tool-to-monitor-http-tcp-etc-web-service-traffic) has many good suggestions.

Comment: In particular a namespace URI can be any URI, it doesn't have to be a resolvable URL.  For example, Microsoft uses the URN `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt` as the namespace URI for their extensions in the .NET XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Whatever the namespace is in a xsd, an xslt or any other xml file, there is no internet request.

The namespace is used to qualified your xml element.

Answer (score 0):

When you conduct an XSLT transformation, the XSLT engine validates the XSLT file. It performs many checks, such as the root element being named `stylesheet`, etc. The engine must also be able to discern literal result elements (like `<table>`) from XSLT-specific elements (like `<xsl:stylesheet>`).

An element is recognized as XSLT-specific when it resides in the XSLT namespace. The value of the URI you posted (http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform) is simply a convention that makes it clear we're talking about XSLT. The prefix being defined (`xsl`) is the prefix used in the XSLT file to qualify the XSLT elements. You can use another prefix if you choose, provided you map it to the XSLT namespace.

Note that it's actually just a URI (an identifier), not a URL (a locator). There is no HTTP request to locate anything, it just identifies an abstract concept (in this case "XSLT").

Comment: Why would the XSLT engine "validate" the XSLT? A perfectly reasonable implementation could be to assume the XSLT is correct, and fail if it's broken. Especially considering that in many scenarios, the same XSLT is  used repeatedly to conduct multiple transforms, in which case extra validation steps would simply be overhead.

Comment: @Dominic: In order to determine whether it's broken, one needs to perform checks. In any case my point was that the engine must discern XSLT-specific elements from non-XSLT-specific ones.

Comment: Attempting to execute the programme is, to some extent, a check of the programme's validity, but checking validity and executing the programme are distinct tasks, although they may overlap. Discerning XSLT elements from others is indeed a programme execution task, as this is necessary. As it happens, to work correctly, a processor must detect whether the root element is xsl:stylesheet, xsl:transform, or something else, which it could legally be in simplified syntax. Just quibbling, though. I take your point.

Comment: @Dominic: An XSLT processor is required to reject invalid stylesheets. Most people, I think, would consider that a program that rejects all invalid documents is by definition doing validation.

Comment: I did wonder for a split second whether I should continue to quibble by arguing that a programme could process XSLT without being a standards-conformant XSLT processor. Best not to go there, I think. I concede utterly and without reservation! :-)