# which HTTP traffic monitoring tool can replace Fiddler

Tags: http, monitoring

I need an HTTP traffic monitoring tool that can replace Fiddler with almost same features...Other than Wireshark, Burpsuite, Charles and plugins(or even dedicated for a browser).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120022/tool-to-monitor-http-tcp-etc-web-service-traffic?rq=1

Comment: Actually the answers are Fiddler, Wireshark and Charles...so it is not an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) is very powerful
Also, there's the [TCPCatcher](http://www.tcpcatcher.org/), it will let you debug any client server application