# Invalid content type error using SAAJ API in Java

Tags: java, soap, content-type, soap-client, saaj

I am trying to access SAOP API using SAAJ. 
I have followed the same code that were present in other answers on creating a SOAP request body and 
calling the SOAP API. 
This particular service does not need any authentication (as mentioned in API doc) nor does it take any input parameters.

```
From WSDL: (copied only relevant content)

<xs:complexType name="getCustomerNames">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType> 
...
<wsdl:operation name="getCustomerNames">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getCustomerNames" name="getCustomerNames"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getCustomerNamesResponse" name="getCustomerNamesResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="tns:SOAPException" name="SOAPException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Below is the Java code that creates the soap body and calls the API

```
SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = scf.createConnection();
SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
String serverURI = "com.webservices.services.authentication";
MessageFactory mf =  MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL); // I tried without parameters as well
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
message.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();           
SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("auth", serverURI);
Name bodyName = sf.createName("getCustomerNames", "auth", serverURI);
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
URL endpoint = new URL(urlendpoint); // urlendpoint is the one that I took from WSDL file service endpoint.
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
connection.close();
```

I get the below error message whenever I execute this. I could not understand why.. The same url is returning the 
proper response when I execute curl command from Unix and post the same request xml that was created by above java code.

```
Feb 14, 2017 3:21:54 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl identifyContentType
SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the server responds with an HTML page instead of a SOAP response. To debug this, you need to intercept the response and look at the content of the HTML page; it will probably contain more information about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am new to both Java and working with APIs. Could you please let me know how do I receive the message as HTML response.  Currently I am receiving the output of Connection.call() as SOAPMessage object type. What should I change this to?

Comment: I get the below response when I use curl command with the same request XML. The response below says its soap, Is it not ?                                                                                      <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><ns2:getCustomerNamesResponse xmlns:ns2="com.webservices.services.authenticationService">
<return>Example</return></ns2:getCustomerNamesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: You can use something like Wireshark to intercept the response.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have access to install wireshark on my system. But I tried posting the messages using chrome "postman" app extension. It returned XML response like above and even through curl command, I am able to interact with all the services.  Isnt the response xml that I posted in my earlier comment a SOAP response? Please let me know

Comment: If you don't have permissions to install Wireshark, there are other tools you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120022/tool-to-monitor-http-tcp-etc-web-service-traffic.